# Error trying to run C# from PowerShell: Invalid token 'using' in

Tags: c#, powershell, interop

Trying to catch when the screen is locked and found a snippet of C# that apparently accomplishes that but every time I try to incorporate into PowerShell, I get a couple of different errors:

```
$Assemblies = @('System', 'System.Messaging')

$type = @"
using System;
using System.Messaging;

public class Win32Session
{
    private const int NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION = 0;
    private const int WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE = 0x2b1;
    private const int WTS_SESSION_LOCK = 0x7;
    private const int WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK = 0x8;

    public event EventHandler MachineLocked;
    public event EventHandler MachineUnlocked;

    public Win32Session()
    {
        ComponentDispatcher.ThreadFilterMessage += ComponentDispatcher_ThreadFilterMessage;
    }

    void ComponentDispatcher_ThreadFilterMessage(ref MSG msg, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE)
        {
            int value = msg.wParam.ToInt32();
            if (value == WTS_SESSION_LOCK)
            {
                OnMachineLocked(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            else if (value == WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK)
            {
                OnMachineUnlocked(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnMachineLocked(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler temp = MachineLocked;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnMachineUnlocked(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler temp = MachineUnlocked;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, e);
        }
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -MemberDefinition $type -Name 'Eventing' -ReferencedAssemblies $Assemblies
```

...if I leave the 'using' statements in the here-string, i get an error about 'using' being an invalid token.  If I remove the 'using' statements and re-run, the compiler complains about not knowing what the MSG type is.  Can anyone assist?  Thx!

Comment: The usings are invalid (that's what `-ReferencedAssemblies` is there for). I also don't know what the MSG type is - it's not defined in either of the referenced assemblies.

Comment: @Adrian Referencing an assembly isn't the same as adding a `using` directive to a .cs file.

Comment: @EdPlunkett true, though this is a PowerShell file, not a C# file. I've added an answer with some better info.

Comment: @Adrian I could have expressed that more good.

Comment: I know I've used the 'using' directive before inside of my here-strings for other p/invoke posh scripts.  ...and the interwebs are littered with posh p/invokes using, 'using'.  I'll try it anyway to see if it works

Comment: I changed my Add-Type line using your recommendations:  Add-Type -MemberDefinition $type -Name 'Eventing' -UsingNamespace @('System.Windows.Interop','System.Windows.Interop.MSG') and the compiler now errors on:  The type or namespace name 'Interop' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows'... ???

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`-UsingNamespace` parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type#-usingnamespace) to serve the purpose that a `using` directive would in a C# file. However, the `MSG` type does appear to be undefined in the referenced namespaces.